# Javascript code is not running on ajax loaded page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am using a WordPress theme called `musik`. The entire pages are loaded using ajax. I need to run the javascript or jquery code on a particular page. I have written it on footer.php. But the js code does not run. But on refreshing the page the js code runs. How can I run the js code on ajax loaded page?

Comment: We can't understand what exactly you are asking? and it's "WordPress" not "workdpress".

Answer (score 0):

For jquery event listener to run, you have to use `on()` method like:

```
$(document).on('click', '.selector', function(){
  // your logic here
});
```

this work well with he dynamic html.